# Can I use baking powder to soften dry beans or chickpeas?

Tags: boiling, beans, chickpeas

Dry beans or chickpeas don't easily soften up after boiling.

Can I use baking powder (not baking soda) to soften dry beans or chickpeas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I prepare dried Chickpeas](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10026/how-should-i-prepare-dried-chickpeas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't use baking powder. Baking powder is part baking soda, and part acid, the two will react with one another and balance each other out, so you won't get the alkaline properties you need.

Comment: So, what alternative can I use?

Comment: @user366312 note that we have to interpret your question as being focused only on the use of baking powder, as stated. If your actual question is "how do I soften chickpeas and beans which stay hard", then it is a duplicate of the one I linked in my answer. So, answers here don't have to discuss what alternatives you have.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

If you have normal, still-good dried chickpeas and you are able to cook them to about the same texture as canned chickpeas, but you want to have softer than that, there are other methods you can use, for example baking soda, or pressure cooking. Baking powder won't have a noticeable softening effect, unless you happen to catch a brand which happens to be quite alkaline after reacting out. But don't rely on it.

If you have too-old chickpeas and they stay hard and appear uncooked, no matter how long you cook them, then there is nothing you can do to get them to the standard texture of cooked chickpeas (like the ones you get in cans). Neither baking powder nor anything else will help. See also [Why won't my beans soften?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/44992/why-wont-my-beans-soften) for more info on that case. You have to either eat them hard, or throw them out.

Comment: I am talking about **baking powder**, not soda.

Comment: @user366312 oh, I missed that. I changed the answer now.